# osm2po network access

Tags: osm2po

How can I access osm2po Webservice in my local network?

I can access `http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService` but if I try (on the same machine) to use the assigned ip address with `http://192.168.1.5:8888/Osm2poService` it doesn't work. Is there any configuration I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for is `service.domain`. Either change it in the `osm2po.config`-File or pass it on the command line `java ... osm2po.jar ... service.domain=192.168.1.5`